# Reshaping Flat JSON Structures with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Currently, I have data in a flat JSON format. We need to convert it to a particular structure.

```
[
   {
      "Region":"WEST",
      "District":"PACIFIC",
      "timestamp":"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Penetration":374
   },
   {
      "Region":"WEST",
      "District":"MOUNTAIN",
      "timestamp":"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Penetration":427
   },
   {
      "Region":"SOUTH",
      "District":"SOUTH WEST",
      "timestamp":"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Penetration":422
   },
   {
      "Region":"SOUTH",
      "District":"SOUTH EAST",
      "timestamp":"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
      "Penetration":410
   }
]
```

It should be as such. Also a constant `"version": "v1"` needs to be added to each object. The flattened result-set can be dynamic. So apart from timestamp key whatever key-value pair are present shall be pulled inside event object.

```
[
  {
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "event": {
      "Penetration":374,
      "Region": "WEST",
      "District": "PACIFIC"
    }
  },
  {
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "event": {
      "Penetration":427,
      "Region": "WEST",
      "District": "MOUNTAIN"
    }
  },
  {
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "event": {
      "Penetration":422,
      "Region": "SOUTH",
      "District": "SOUTH WEST"
    }
  }
  {
    "version": "v1",
    "timestamp": "2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "event": {
      "Penetration":410
      "Region": "SOUTH",
      "District": "SOUTH EAST"
    }
  }           
]
```

Comment: So what's the problem? After parsing, this looks like running one iteration of `.map()` on the array.

Comment: being new to javascript I was not aware of ...rest parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply make use of `map` method:

```js
var data=[ { "Region":"WEST", "District":"PACIFIC", "timestamp":"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z", "Penetration":374 }, { "Region":"WEST", "District":"MOUNTAIN", "timestamp":"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z", "Penetration":427 }, { "Region":"SOUTH", "District":"SOUTH WEST", "timestamp":"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z", "Penetration":422 }, { "Region":"SOUTH", "District":"SOUTH EAST", "timestamp":"2018-12-28T00:00:00.000Z", "Penetration":410 }];

var result = data.map(({timestamp, ...events})=>({version:'v1',timestamp, events}));

console.log(result);
```